# YouTube Data API v3 - Error 500 getting playlist list

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

I am facing  a  **500 internal server error** message when trying to **get the playlists from the Pop music-Topic channel** ( https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCE80FOXpJydkkMo-BYoJdEg):

```
"error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
}
```

I am using the **youtube.playlists.list** request from the Youtube Data Api v3.

You can test it on the Google api explorer by following this link:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlists.list?part=snippet&channelId=UCE80FOXpJydkkMo-BYoJdEg&_h=1&

What's strange is that it worked as intented some days ago.

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your request and I also get the 500 error. According to this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Additional_response_codes), the 500 (Internal error) is a response code that indicates that YouTube experienced an error handling a request. You could retry the request at a later time.

I tried different channel id and get a successful request. Here is the request that I use.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=UCnExqEQyG6WemMK9hpQcoeQ&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

I don't know if the channel has the issue or the YouTube itself. But if you try different channel, it works.

So I suggest like the error says, retry the request at a later time. Because like you said it worked some days ago.

For more information, you can check this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4642).